# Why test frameworks are included in development bundle

Tags: rubygems, bundler

For example, testing frameworks like [Rspec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) or [Jasmine](https://semaphoreapp.com/blog/2013/05/28/jasmine-javascript-tests-for-continuous-integration.html) asks you to add their gems both onto test and development group. Why is that?

I'd expect them to live only in test group.

Comment: this might be due to rake tasks etc that are provided by those gems, but honestly, i don't have a real idea. at least rspec forces the `RAILS_ENV` to be `test` anyhow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For generators to work. If you didn't include in development you would have to run `RAILS_ENV=test rails g ...`